# How to I write a string with quotes and hash tags in yaml?

Tags: yaml

I have blocks of text that I want to import into a yaml file. The text includes special characters and I do not want to have to go line by line and escape each special character. How do I write the following as a string in Yaml without it converting anything to comments or choaking?

```
html: <p class='myParagraph'>The teacher said, "Use a #2 pencil."<br/>Question 1: 1\2=?</p>
```

There are single quotes, double quotes, angle brackets, forward and back slashes, and a hash.

Answer (score 0):

### Context

- YAML 1.1

### Problem

- OlegOlaf McCoyly wishes to specify a string in YAML, where one or more embedded characters in the string could cause [delimiter collision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter#Delimiter_collision) with the YAML syntax itself, thus breaking the YAML file.

### Solution

Specify the block of text as a YAML multiline-string:

```
   html: |
       <p class='myParagraph'>"Use a #2 pencil."<br/>Question 1: 1\2=?</p>
```